# Problem understanding 今度一度

Tags: words

I'm having trouble trying to understand a fragment from a dialogue between two students in the book "An Integrated Approach to Intermediate Japanese".

I do know that 今度 means "now", "next time", or "another time", and 一度 means "once". But in the conversation between the two students they use 今度一度:

> 加藤: でも上手じゃありませんよ。
>
> トム: **今度一度**やりましょうか。

How should I understand 今度一度 in the previous fragment of the dialogue?

Comment: Why do you think 今度 means now?

Comment: @virmaior [Why do you](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/27652/m0u/%E4%BB%8A%E5%BA%A6/) [think it can't?](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%8A%E5%BA%A6)  (Note that the OP didn't say it has that meaning in this particular example.)

Comment: @snailboat. Say, on that goo.ne.jp link you posted, the first example was 「今度こそきっと勝つぞ」. Without any context, is there anything preventing one from interpreting it as "I will win next time for sure" instead?

Comment: Somehow I misread his original question as not having the other two defs. It is strange to me that that definition comes up first -- considering it is not the clearest translation for any of the examples

Answer (score 5):

First, 「[今度]{こんど}」 can be used to refer to an event occuring in all of the three time frames below:

> The recent past
>
> The present
>
> The near future

Though I have no idea what bilingual dictionaries say about this, you could verify this with any medium-size monolingual Japanese dictionary.  Which one of the three the word 「今度」 refers to will entirely depend on the context.

When the World Cup ended the other day, I said to a few people, 「今度のワールドカップはなんかつまんなかったね。」 = "The World Cup this time was kinda boring, wasn't it?"  (I said it because Japan got eliminated very quickly.)

> In the phrase 「[今度一度]{こんどいちど}」, 「今度」 can only mean one thing out of the three mentioned above.  That is "in the near future".  It does not specifically have to be "the very next time" [加藤]{かとう} and トム meet.  It just means "one of the next few (but not many) times we are meeting in the near future."

「一度」 does not have to be translated as "once" everytime you see it.  In the phrase 「今度一度」, 「一度」 just means "sometime".

> 「今度一度」, therefore, means "sometime soon", "sometime in the near future", or even just "next time".

Answer (score 1):

As you understand, in this case, "今度" means "next time" or "another time".
And "一度" means "once".

The problem is relationship between word.

"once" is related to after part.

"一度やりましょうか" means "Let's try one time".
Then add "今度"(next time). "Let's play one time, in next time.".

Ex.
(Tom: Mr.Kato, do you play tennis?)
(Kato: I play tennis before.)
加藤: でも上手じゃありませんよ。
-> Kato: But, I'm not good player.
トム: 今度一度やりましょうか。
-> Tom: Let's play one game, next time.